# VBA Excel: how to get row and column number of named range?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I have the following problem and it's driving me NUTS! I work on a large database program in Excel, and I'm trying to retrieve the row and column numbers of specific named ranges. The following code used to work (temp_entryvalue is the name of the range):

```
temp_datafile_row = Workbooks(datafile_filepath).Worksheets(temp_datafile_worksheet).Range(temp_entryvalue).Row
temp_datafile_col = Workbooks(datafile_filepath).Worksheets(temp_datafile_worksheet).Range(temp_entryvalue).Column
```

I get the ole' Error 1004. Troubleshooting a bit, the problem here seems to be that the range associated with temp_entryvalue is hidden in the excel sheet, however the name is defined and there is a row and column number assigned to.

This however, all used to work. Until I changed one thing: instead of writing directly to the database excel worksheet, I first put everything in an array, so that only at the very end I open the database worksheet and copy all the data. Before I did this, everything used to work fine.

So how do I fix this? How do I retrieve the row and column number of a Named Range that is hidden, but DOES have a row and column number associated to it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a strange question you are having there. However, in general getting the column and row of a hidden worksheet should be trivial, thus I suppose you are making some small mistake somewhere.

Open a new Excel file and try this code:

```
Option Explicit    
Public Sub TestMe()      

    Dim tempEntryvalue As Range

    Set tempEntryvalue = Worksheets(1).Range("A1:Z10")
    Worksheets(1).Visible = xlVeryHidden        
    Debug.Print tempEntryvalue.Row
    Debug.Print tempEntryvalue.Column  

End Sub
```

---

Or if you really mean `NamedRange` (your code looks like if the range is declared as a variable), then this is probably the easiest solution:

```
Public Sub TestMe()    

    Debug.Print [temp_entryvalue].Row
    Debug.Print [temp_entryvalue].Column
    Debug.Print Range("temp_entryvalue").Row
    Debug.Print Range("temp_entryvalue").Column    

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. However, I opened a clean new worksheet, pasted your first bit of code into the worksheet code section, and it's still giving me the 1004 error. Any ideas what this could mean?

Comment: Which first bit? @TheBrainletExterminator

Comment: Under "Open a new Excel file and try this code:" and above "Or if you really mean ..."

Comment: @TheBrainletExterminator - that is strange. Where do you put the code? Do you put it in a module? Are you sure that you open a New Excel workbook? Can you restart your PC and try again? (I am not joking about the resetart, it can be that you have more than 1 workbook opened and you are somehow calling the wrong code).

Comment: Yep, new workbook, pasted the code behind the sheet. Just restarted my computer - same issue.

Comment: @TheBrainletExterminator - put it behind a module, not behind a sheet.

Comment: Did that, still Error 1004. This time with the message that property Visible of class "Worksheet" can not be set up (Excel at my job is in my native language, so I'm not sure what it says literally).

Comment: If you have only one sheet in the workbook, you cannot hide it and you might be getting error on the line `Worksheets(1).Visible = xlVeryHidden` Right?

Comment: @sktneer Oh I did not notice that! You're absolutely right, now I don't get the error.

Comment: @TheBrainletExterminator - so I suppose you were using Excel-2016?